# @tanstack/react-table v8: How to get next row when sorted

Tags: row, react-table, tanstack

I have a **sorted(!)** @tanstack-table v8 (aka react-table).

In each tr there is an onClick-Handler which gives me access to the current row-object.

So far so good.

But how do I get access to the next (or previous) row?

Sadly row.index isn't working as it doesn't reflect the sorting. There's no "sortedIndex" as far as I can see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found `Table.getSortedRowModel()`, which returns the **sorted** row model!

Link to the docs: https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/features/sorting#getsortedrowmodel

I use the following to get the row-index of a row containing `mySearchValue` in a specific column of the table:

```
let currentIndex = table
    .getSortedRowModel()
    .rows.findIndex((row) => row.getValue("<ColumnKey>") == mySearchValue);
```

Using this its quite easy to get a value in a column of the i.e. previous row

```
let prevRowFieldValue = table.getSortedRowModel()
    .rows[currentIndex - 1].getValue("<ColumnKey>");
```

For me this works perfectly, maybe it helps someone!